# Why is Chrome faster than Safari though they both use Webkit?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, browser

I feel the difference between Safari 5.1.5 and Google Chrome 18.0 on Mac OS X 10.7.3 are very noticeable. The difference are most clear when it comes to reloading pages or XHR requests. Do Chrome somehow cached all these requests in a different way than Safari or have Google "hacked" Webkit to be speedier?

Thanks! =)

Comment: For one, they use different JS engines. Safari uses SquirrelFish/Nitro, Chrome uses V8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed very interesting, as the Webkit-Engine is build by Apple (!), not Google. To answer your question: Safari 5.1.5 uses Webkit 534.55.3, Chrome 18 uses 535.19. A minor difference, but still a plus for Chrome.

I my opinion the increase in "speed" is simply made by the way the browser renders a page: Safari seems to rebuild everything from scratch while Chrome (similar to Opera) build up the page even if it's not fully loaded. Chrome has done a lot of these "feels faster" improvements (like loading browser GUI first, then loading libs. firefox does it other way round. which feels longer).

Update: An interesting article from Paul Irish of the Webkit Team on this topic. ["Why Webkits aren't the same everywhere"](http://paulirish.com/2013/webkit-for-developers/)

Comment: Thanks for the details, really interesting! So either Apple or Google just grabbing the most stable Webkit version and add it to their browser but actually do a lot of modifications to it? Do they open source or "give back" any of the successful changes to Webkit?

Sorry if these questions sound dumb but I lived believing Safari and Chrome was the exact same browser except the toolbar navigation and name. =)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's very interesting, as Chrome isn't anything special on PC. In fact, on my Windows 7 PC, Safari is my tertiary browser behind Maxthon-3 (operates like IE, but better) and Opera (1-key window cycling and page resize beats all).

I've had issue with Chrome like: 404-errors on the first submit of a common url: memory "devouring" when launching with multiple tabs.